# Computing integer partitions

Tags: python, performance

I am trying to calculate the number of partitions of numbers from 1 to 10<sup>7</sup>. I am using the pentagonal number theorem to achieve that, which provides a way to calculate the number of partitions of \$n\$, let's call it \$P(n) = P(n-1) + P(n-2) - P(n-5) - P(n-7) + ...\$ So \$P(n)\$ depends on different \$P(n-x)\$, where \$x\$ goes from 1 to \$n\$. Anyway, long story short, I am using two loops, one that goes from 1 to 10<sup>7</sup> and the other one that uses the \$x\$'s defined and calculate after a specific formula. As you can imagine, the code goes quite slow. Is there any way I can improve the speed of these for loops?

P.S. I have tried using numpy arrays, but I am not really comfortable with them and unfortunately it made the code even slower.

```
def build_list(new_limit, k):
   list_of_p_minus = list()
   while k < new_limit:
      list_of_p_minus.append(k*(2*k-1))
      list_of_p_minus.append(k*(2*k+1))
      k = k+1
   return list_of_p_minus


def loop_through_numbers(limit, list_of_p_minus):
   p_dict = dict()
   p_dict[0] = 1
   p_dict[1] = 1
   aux = 2
   aux_index = 1
   for number in range(2, limit+1):
      if aux == number
          m = weird_index % 4
          if m == 1 or m == 2:
             p_dict[number] = -1
          else:
             p_dict[number] = 1
          aux = aux + (aux_index + 1) * 2
          aux_index += 1
      else:
          p_dict[number] = 0
      for element in range(0, len(list_of_p_minus)):
          if element % 4 == 0 or element % 4 == 1:
             try:
                p_dict[number] += p_dict[number-list_of_p_minus[element]]
             except KeyError:
                break
          else:
             try:
                p_dict[number] -= p_dict[number-list_of_p_minus[element]]
             except KeyError:
                break
   return
```

Comment: Is this actually working code, and if so how do you use it? I can't see anywhere where `weird_index` is assigned to, and the method which looks like the main one doesn't seem to return or output anything.

Comment: it was a mistake, weird_index = aux_index

Comment: How would this be used, do you have a usage example? Does it produce the correct result?